# How to deploy in render.com this kind of codebase?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, render

[image: code base]

I got this error ::
GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OLJa9mm net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Everything is good but the socket is not working...!!!

```
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  pingTimeout: 60000,
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    // credentials: true,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem:

```
socket.current = io('http://localhost:5000/%27') =>
socket.current = io('YOURBACKENDURL')
```